# Auto-resize table when text from a column is to big

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have a simple table that I manage to make it to scale when text is too big by using p{4.7cm}. Here is the code:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\scalebox{1.0}{
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|}
        \cline{2-3} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{p{4.7cm}|}{RIGHT} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{LEFT}   \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test1} & 1& 1\\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{test2} & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

And here is how it looks like :

[image]

I set p{4.7cm} just for the RIGHT but I would like in the case when text length is less than 4.7cm the column size to be equal with the text size.

[image]

Is possible to do such a thing?

Thank you

Comment: always avoid `\scalebox` around tables, if you do use it then avoid adding space, you are forcing a word space inside the box before and after the table, use `{\begin{tabular}...\end{tabular}}` not  `{ \begin{tabular}...\end{tabular} }`

Answer (score 1):

tabulary columns can be set natural width up to a maximum width for the whole table

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}



\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|c|L|c|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&RIGHT &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}

\bigskip


    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|c|L|c|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
 &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}


\bigskip


    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|c|L|c|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
 &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}



\end{document}
```

---

or for all columns as requested in comments

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabulary}

\begin{document}



\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\tymin{.2\linewidth}

    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&RIGHT &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}

\bigskip


    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
 &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}


\bigskip


    \begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|L|L|L|}
        \cline{2-3}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}&
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT RIGHT
 &   LEFT   \\ \hline
        test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
        test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
    \end{tabulary}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This works nice, but if I want to make all the columns to have this property, how should I do? If I try to add \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} doesn't really work. I need to make this for a project and I am a beginner with latex.

Comment: @Adrian make them all L

Comment: If I mark all as L some of them are out of the table. [link](https://ibb.co/iOaDue)

Comment: @Adrian I added an example

Comment: Hi David. Still, this doesn't solve my problem. If I add more text in the first left cell the text override.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\convertXColumns

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|X|c|}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}& short &   short   \\ \hline
test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\bigskip
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{|c|X|c|}\cline{2-3}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \blindtext &  LEFT  \\ \hline
test1 & 1& 1\\ \hline
test2 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Helbert. This works fine on ideal cases, but if I put to much text in a cell with that has "1" value the table goes out of the page. For me is important that all cell to break the text if is too big.